# Spring: Apply security to method

Tags: spring

I want to secure a method located in a controller.  The method name is listAdminTickets and is located in the package org.srac.returnticket.web.ReturnticketController.java

I've setup my security context as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login.jsp"/>
        <intercept-url access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" pattern="/secure/*"/>
        <form-login authentication-failure-url="/pages/login.jsp?login_error=true" login-page="/pages/login.jsp"/> 
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/pages/logout-redirect.jsp"/>
        <remember-me key="PartReturnRMKey" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">

    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl" id="userDetailsService">
        <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="springSecurityDataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT username,password,enabled FROM Users WHERE username = ?"/>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT u.username, a.authorityname FROM Users u JOIN Users_Authorities ua on u.id = ua.user_id JOIN Authorities a on ua.authorities_id = a.id WHERE u.username = ?"/>
    </beans:bean>
<global-method-security>
        <protect-pointcut access="ROLE_ADMIN" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.web.ReturnticketController.*listAdmin*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.service.PartlistService.*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.service.ReturnticketService.*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.service.StorelistService.*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.dao.PartlistDAO.*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.dao.ReturnticketDAO.*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.dao.StorelistDAO.*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.dao.TicketnoteDAO.*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.secure.UsersDAO.*(..))"/>
        <protect-pointcut access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED" expression="execution(* org.srac.partreturn.secure.AuthoritiesDAO.*(..))"/>

    </global-method-security>
</beans:beans>
```

It does not work as I can login with a user account, past the link into the browser and get to the page.  Security does appear to be working as I use this code to prevent anyone with Role_User from seeing the button

```
<security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN"> 
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/pages/admin/menu.jsp" />    
</security:authorize>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Here is the log results when accessing the page I want protected -

```
    2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 14159113972
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractEntityManagerImpl - Looking for a JTA transaction to join
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractEntityManagerImpl - No JTA transaction found
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractEntityManagerImpl - Looking for a JTA transaction to join
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] JDBCContext - successfully registered Synchronization
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] SQLStatementLogger - select returntick0_.TID as TID0_, returntick0_.ClosedDate as ClosedDate0_, returntick0_.ClosedName as ClosedName0_, returntick0_.Company as Company0_, returntick0_.Cost as Cost0_, returntick0_.EntryDate as EntryDate0_, returntick0_.EntryName as EntryName0_, returntick0_.entryNote as entryNote0_, returntick0_.HelpDeskTicket as HelpDesk9_0_, returntick0_.InstallDate as Install10_0_, returntick0_.InstallName as Install11_0_, returntick0_.ModelNum as ModelNum0_, returntick0_.PartName as PartName0_, returntick0_.PID as PID0_, returntick0_.ReturnDate as ReturnDate0_, returntick0_.ReturnName as ReturnName0_, returntick0_.ReturnType as ReturnType0_, returntick0_.RMA as RMA0_, returntick0_.SerialNum as SerialNum0_, returntick0_.ShipDate as ShipDate0_, returntick0_.ShipTag as ShipTag0_, returntick0_.SiteID as SiteID0_, returntick0_.VendorPN as VendorPN0_ from PartReturn.dbo.ReturnTicket returntick0_
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Loader - result row: EntityKey[org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1000]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Loader - result row: EntityKey[org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1001]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Loader - result row: EntityKey[org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1002]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Loader - result row: EntityKey[org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1023]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Loader - result row: EntityKey[org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1024]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,232 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Loader - result row: EntityKey[org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1026]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractBatcher - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1000]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1000]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1001]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1001]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1002]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1002]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1023]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1023]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1024]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1024]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1026]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket#1026]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractFlushingEventListener - processing flush-time cascades
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractFlushingEventListener - dirty checking collections
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Collections - Collection found: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1000], was: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1000] (uninitialized)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Collections - Collection found: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1001], was: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1001] (uninitialized)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Collections - Collection found: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1002], was: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1002] (uninitialized)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Collections - Collection found: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1023], was: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1023] (uninitialized)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Collections - Collection found: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1024], was: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1024] (uninitialized)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Collections - Collection found: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1026], was: [org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket.ticketnotes#1026] (uninitialized)
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 6 objects
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 6 collections
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Printer - listing entities:
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Printer - org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket{shipTag=, partName=NCR Monitor 15", modelNum=OA10351, entryName=DMK, helpDeskTicket=334455, returnName=DMK, pid=300001, closedDate=null, shipDate=2014-10-30 00:00:00, entryDate=2014-11-01 13:30:00, returnDate=null, cost=294.3000, returnType=Store Returned, installName=null, vendorPn=A123, siteId=1207, installDate=null, rma=RMA1122334455, company=NCR, ticketnotes=<uninitialized>, tid=1023, serialNum=213Z123, closedName=null, entryNote=null}
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Printer - org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket{shipTag=null, partName=3M XT1 HEADSET EXCHANGE, modelNum=XT1EX, entryName=DKnutson, helpDeskTicket=527879, returnName=null, pid=200001, closedDate=null, shipDate=2014-08-15 00:00:00, entryDate=2014-08-14 00:00:00, returnDate=null, cost=865.0000, returnType=null, installName=DKnutson, vendorPn=XT1EX, siteId=35, installDate=2014-11-11 00:00:00, rma=RMA13213972, company=CE, ticketnotes=<uninitialized>, tid=1000, serialNum=1234, closedName=null, entryNote=null}
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Printer - org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket{shipTag=null, partName=NCR Monitor 15", modelNum=OA10351, entryName=DMK, helpDeskTicket=334455, returnName=, pid=300001, closedDate=null, shipDate=2014-10-30 00:00:00, entryDate=2014-11-01 13:30:00, returnDate=null, cost=294.3000, returnType=, installName=, vendorPn=A123, siteId=1207, installDate=2014-11-02 00:00:00, rma=RMA1122334455, company=NCR, ticketnotes=<uninitialized>, tid=1024, serialNum=213Z123, closedName=, entryNote=null}
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Printer - org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket{shipTag=null, partName=NCR Kiwi, modelNum=P823F001, entryName=DKnutson, helpDeskTicket=555686, returnName=null, pid=300012, closedDate=null, shipDate=2014-08-18 00:00:00, entryDate=2014-08-17 00:00:00, returnDate=null, cost=600.0000, returnType=null, installName=null, vendorPn=P823F001:US KPS Controller No DVI/ANT, siteId=132, installDate=2014-09-01 00:00:00, rma=RMA01938373, company=NCR, ticketnotes=<uninitialized>, tid=1002, serialNum=2567, closedName=, entryNote=null}
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Printer - org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket{shipTag=TA123123123, partName=NCR Terminal - Drive Thru, modelNum=P1220, entryName=DKnutson, helpDeskTicket=12356, returnName=DMK, pid=300010, closedDate=null, shipDate=2014-08-17 00:00:00, entryDate=2014-08-16 00:00:00, returnDate=2014-11-11 00:00:00, cost=4507.8500, returnType=Store Returned, installName=admin, vendorPn=P1220-1214-BA:CAP LPB 4GBuD WES 2GB B2 AED, siteId=975, installDate=null, rma=RMA29384745, company=NCR, ticketnotes=<uninitialized>, tid=1001, serialNum=3421, closedName=, entryNote=null}
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] Printer - org.srac.partreturn.domain.Returnticket{shipTag=777777777777777777777, partName=NCR Terminal - Front Counter, modelNum=P1220, entryName=DMK, helpDeskTicket=332244, returnName=DMK, pid=300009, closedDate=null, shipDate=2014-10-29 00:00:00, entryDate=2014-11-02 14:04:00, returnDate=2014-11-02 00:00:00, cost=4470.3600, returnType=Store Returned, installName=dknutson, vendorPn=P1220-6025, siteId=18296, installDate=2014-11-11 00:00:00, rma=RMA1234567, company=NCR, ticketnotes=<uninitialized>, tid=1026, serialNum=Z1234, closedName=null, entryNote=null}
2014-11-13 12:43:17,247 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ConnectionManager - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
2014-11-13 12:43:17,264 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
2014-11-13 12:43:17,264 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ConnectionManager - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
```

Comment: Try enabling debug level logging and see if the execution(* org.srac.partreturn.web.ReturnticketController.*listAdmin*(..)) pointcut is applied correctly. Also just to eliminate the obvious - this will protect your controllers method url and not your page url.

Comment: Not sure how to enable debugging on myeclipse

Comment: Not remote debugging, just set loglevel to debug. Depending on your logging implementation you can use log4j.properties or say logback.xml...and set root logger level to debug.